# Calculate $\int_0^a \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^4+x^2+1}}$ in terms of $\int_0^a \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

Define the function $L$ as follows:
$$L(a)=\int_0^a \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}$$
I‘ve been trying to calculate the following integral in terms of $L$:
$$I(a)=\int_0^a \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^4+x^2+1}}$$
So far I‘ve tried lots of substitutions in this integral to reduce it to some value of $L$, a constant multiple of a value of $L$, or some sum of values of $L$ multiplied by other functions of $a$, without any luck.

Can anyone find a clever substitution that allows $I(a)$ to be calculated in terms of some combination of values of $L(\cdot)$?

Answer (score 0):

That would imply some identity relating values of the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind $\text{EllipticF}(z,k)$ (in Maple's notation) at $k=i$ and $k = (1+i\sqrt{3})/2$.  I'm not aware of such identities (not that this is necessarily definitive).